# Prolog query exercise

Tags: prolog

Here are my given clauses

```
beats(rock, scissors).
beats(scissors, paper).
beats(paper, rock).

better(battleaxe, scissors).
better(lightsabre, battleaxe).
better(boulder, rock).
better(adamantium, boulder).
better(palisade, paper).
better(nanomesh, palisade).

uses(wolverine, adamantium).
uses(vader, lightsabre).
uses(conan, battleaxe).
uses(richard, rock).

win(X,Y) :- beats(X,Y).
win(X,Y) :- better(X,Y).
win(X,Y) :- better(X,'underscore here'), beats('underscore here',Y). 
win(X,Y) :- better(X,A), better(Y,B), win(A,B).
win(X,Y) :- uses(X,A), uses(Y,B), !, win(A,B).

play(X,Y,X) :- win(X,Y).
play(X,Y,Y) :- win(Y,X).
```

the question is asking what result i would get from

```
?- win(X, nanomesh).
```

the answer is supposed to be `X = lightsabre`. However I really do not get why.

Could anyone explain this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways how you can try to understand this particular query. One way, is to add goals **`false`** into your program, such that you still get the same answer. By adding **`false`** the program is specialized. If it then still gets the same answer, we know that a responsible part is in the visible area. The <s>strike-through</s> parts indicate clauses you now can ignore completely.

```
beats(rock, scissors) :- false.
beats(scissors, paper).
beats(paper, rock) :- false.

better(battleaxe, scissors).
better(lightsabre, battleaxe).
better(boulder, rock) :- false.
better(adamantium, boulder) :- false.
better(palisade, paper).
better(nanomesh, palisade).

win(X,Y) :- beats(X,Y).
win(X,Y) :- false, better(X,Y).
win(X,Y) :- false, better(X,'underscore here'), beats('underscore here',Y).
win(X,Y) :- better(X,A), better(Y,B), win(A,B).

?- win(lightsabre, nanomesh).
```

So you have two chains:

```
nanomesh   -> palisade  -> paper` 
lightsabre -> battleaxe -> scissors
```

And finally `scissors` beat `paper`.

Not sure I agree with this kind of reasoning, though.